# django template block overriding

Tags: django, django-templates, overriding

I'm developing an application in django and I don't know how to use the Django template system to achieve block overriding using template inheritance.

I've got a `base.html` template:

```
[...]
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
[...]
```

there's `index.html` template that displays a JS slider (it's content reside in `body` tag directly):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
// some javascript/css slider stuff here
{% endblock %}
```

and there are some dynamic content pages: `list.html`, `form.html`, etc (their content shall reside in some `div` containers). I define `container.html` somehow like the following:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container marketing">
    <div class="container">
        {% put overriden "content" block here %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And then I can define `list.html` like this:

```
{% extends "container.html" %} # note what I'm extending here!

{% block content %}
this is my list
{% endblock %}
```

**Why?**

I want to keep my base template as generic as possible (e.g. to enable client-side slider - with no `div` containers). And I want to wrap most of my dynamic pages (list, form, etc.) in the same HTML container code. Since I don't want to repeat this code, this should be available in one template (a template to be extended by list, form, etc).

I know I could define another block inside. But maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, what you effectively want is for container.html to look like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container marketing">
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So that you're redefining what the `content` block is for templates that inherit container.html?

**I don't think this is possible without changing the template language itself**, but it's something I've found myself wanting to do as well. I don't like sub-templates having to care whether they inherit a full-width template, or a left-hand-sidebar template or the base template in order to know which block name to put the primary content in.

Comment: I'm afraid your solution doesn't work:

Error during template rendering

In template /var/www/Python/djninja/djninja/templates/container.html, error at line 6
'block' tag with name 'body' appears more than once
`1 {% extends "base_generic.html" %}
2 
3 {% block body %}
4     <div class="container marketing">
5         <div class="container">
6             {% block body %}put some content here{% endblock %}
7         </div>
8     </div>
9 {% endblock %}
`

Comment: That's why I said it isn't possible :)

Answer (score 0):

On a first thought I think you can have two aproacches:

- rename inner content block as content_inner
- have two block or more block contents templates and extend one or the other from your view or settings (or session or whatever). To expand this last option:

base.html, content_col_right.html, content_col_left.html, etc, and in content.html:

```
{% extends variable_name %}
```

There are more options, but makes your template html (ids and classes) very attached to your view code. Like

Tip: Don't be afraid of context processor and make your own.

Comment: your first idea is the same as I wrote `I know I could define another block inside`. I can't clearly get the idea behind your second idea. I can see that you dynamize the name of the extended template (by making it a variable) but how can I make use of it?

Comment: I read again your post and realize you are aware of solution 1. On the other hand I am more confused with your question. Maybe what you really want is a library to produce HTML from python. Templates are for giving most of freedom to designers and I think (sorry if I supposed wrong) you are looking for an standard (and inmutable) set of html components to be reused. Am I wrong?
Also template tags can inject this components (or templates like "list.html","table.html","slider.html") easily in your templates with appropiate ids and classes to make javascript work.